# How to set session use by asp.net web api with jquery (not use mvc)

Tags: asp.net

I want to  know how to set session using ASP.Net Web API (not ASP.net MVC) and jQuery.

Any idea?

Comment: why you need to make session in webapi? Also what you tried paste your code ?

Comment: my project cross origin request base . So i need session in web api with jquery

Answer (score 0):

Rule of thumb is not to use sessions with Web API due to the stateless nature of the web services. but you can access session modifying  **Global.ascx** 
file in the project.

```
protected void Application_PostAuthorizeRequest()
{
   HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(SessionStateBehavior.Required);
}
```

to set the same session between multiple servers you can use single SQL instance
as the [session state](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/317604/how-to-configure-sql-server-to-store-asp-net-session-state).

then you can use that session inside your controller code

```
[HttpPost]
public string GetSetSession(string stringValue)
{
    Session["session_key"]=stringValue;
    return Session["session_key"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: I can set thisprotected void Application_PostAuthorizeRequest()
{
   HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(SessionStateBehavior.Required);
}   Its very usefull.

Comment: But my problem . session set web api with jquery

Comment: multiple server and client side

Comment: for multiple server scenario, you can set a centralized SQL server DB as the session storage by editing web.config. then you can create a new controller method to set session value.

Comment: @SourabhDhiman check the updated answer. from client-side, you can use Jquery Ajax to call the mentioned controller method.